# Setting service.json path to the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I followed this tutorial for connecting Firestore to my C# Xamarin Android project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptEtTNQ0dXg but he did this in WPF, I need this for Xamarin Android App.

At around 13:58 he inserts the path of the "service.json" file to the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable, but this doesn't work for me. It returns this error: http://prntscr.com/wka3rt
Any idea what else I could do?

Here is my code:

```cs
string path = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "service.json");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
```

This is where my file is located:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Okay, I moved the service.json file to the Android project, and added this code:

```cs
string fileName = "service.json";
                string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
```

And I get this error: http://prntscr.com/wkac8a

Comment: you can't include files in a library project like that.  The file should be included in your Android project and you should be able to read it just using the relative file name.  AppDataDirectory is not the correct path.

Comment: first, do not stuff code into comments.  Edit your post to add additional information.  Second, do not post code or errors as images.  Third, be sure your file has a build action of content, and try using just "filename" or "./filename" for the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the youtube link, it seems you want to use the **Firebase Database**. It works without the json file for the database. You could google for the Xamarin.forms firebase realtime database. You would find a lot of samples.

If you want to use the **Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification**,  you need to download the google-services.json file.

- For the MS docs, you could check the link for rference.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows
- You could also download the source file from the link.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/firebase-fcmnotifications/